# UA to GA4 equivalent TransactionsPerSession with custom dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

### Universal Analytics

In the past I used the Google Analytics API to get conversion rate for specific events.
The dimensions and metrics were:

```
Dimentions
 - ga:eventLable
Metrics
 - ga:transactions
 - ga:transactionsPerSession
```

I was able to retrieve the data successfully.

### GA4

Since Universal Analytics properties will stop processing data soon, I need to switch to Google Analytics 4. However, I noticed that the `TransactionsPerSession` is not available in the Google Analytics 4 API. I have tried many different metrics, but most of them return `0`, including `Transactions`.

```
Dimentions
 - customEvent:eventLable
Metrics
 - transactions
 - sessionCoversionRate
 - userCoversionRate
 - purchaserCoversionRate
 - ...
```

Is there any other way to get TransactionsPerSession(Ecommerce Conversion Rate)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sessionCoversionRate` dimension, however, if the value of `transaction` is also 0 it means that you have an upstream tracking problem.